# If current results hold, Man City would win PL title

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning, word-difference, british-english, will-would

[image]

The line under the scoreboard says

> If current results hold, Man City **would** win PL title.

I am totally confused about why *would* is there. It describes a particular condition (winning the game) and the consequences that **will** follow if the condition turns out to be true.

My version undoubtedly would be

> If current results hold, Man City **will** win PL title.

and I would like to figure out why the author preferred *would* to *will*. Would it change the meaning of the sentence if they put *will* instead?

Doesn't *would* bring uncertainty? Does it show that the author doesn't believe Man City can win the game? It's weird because Man City were leading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your version

> If current results hold, Man City will win [the] PL title.

is perfectly grammatical, although I would prefer not to eliminate the "the", except in the space-limited context of the online display in the image. In fact I think it is better than the version with "would".

There is uncertainty here in a sense, because no one yet knows if the current results will in fact persist, so no one knows for sure who will win. Therefore the use of "would" is reasonable. Besides the "rules" on the use of "would" vs "will" are not strictly adhered to by may, particularly in informal writing, which this surely is.

I can't say why whoever wrote this line chose 'would" over "will". Quite probably the writer didn't give much thought to the choice. "Would" sounded OK, so s/he went with it. But your analysis of the reasons to chose "will" is quite correct.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate it. If the score remains 1:2, Man City will win the title. It's a very straightforward condition, there is no doubt what will happen to the winner... I guess it's hard to convey it in the first part of the sentence. If we were to write "If the current result held, Man City would win the title", we would be basically saying that Man City have a slim chance to win...

Comment: it's also unclear to me why the plural form "current result**s**" was used (and with *the* dropped). I understand the was dropped probably for the sake of conciseness, but why the plural?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko See my answer for why "results" is plural.

Comment: You said it's surely informal... It was on TV watched by many people, at the finishing line of the main football contest in the country. How come is it informal?)

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko Sports writing in general, and particularly headlines, are pretty much always in an informal register of English. "Informal" does not mean 'private". Much TV communication is an an informal register.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the precise details of the PL championship, but you are right the choice of "will" or "would" is based on the level of certainty or uncertainty in the prediction.

Note the screen shot says "results", plural. That suggests the actual championship winner will depend on the results of (perhaps several) *other* games, which may not have started yet. In that situation, the "result holding" may be unlikely, and "would" (suggesting uncertainty) is a better choice of word than "will" (suggesting certainty about the final result).

Having just checked the news reports, the real-life situation was that BHA took an early lead in the match, and were then overtaken by MC, so it was not impossible that BHA would eventually win. And the runners-up in the championship were also playing, and having won their match ended only one point behind the MC. In other words, there was *very little* certainty about who would be the eventual championship winner when that headline appeared on the screen.